# Derivation in 2.50 Jaynes Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, taylor-expansion

With the product rule and definition of S function (for complement), we define x = w(A|C) and y = w(B|C)  :

$$x\times S[\frac {S(y)}x] = y \times S[\frac{S(x)}y], 0 \le S(y) \le x,
 0 \le x \le 1 \tag{2.45}$$

Then he drew a conclusion that the points consisted in xy plane lying in the unit square $$0 \le x, y \le 1 $$ and on or above the $$ y = S(x) $$
Jaynes wanted to prove the that the shape of curve determined by what 2.45 says for points lying infinitesimally above it.

Then Jaynes set $$y = S(x) + \epsilon, \epsilon \rightarrow 0+.$$ the two terms in 2.45 tends to S(1) = 0, but at different rates.

By define a new variable q(x,y) by $$ \frac{S(x)}y = 1 - \exp\{-q\} \tag{ 2.48}$$

There is a direct result which confuses me:
Considering now x, q as the independent variables, we have from (2.48)
$$ S(y) = S[S(x)] + \exp\{-q\}S(x)S'[S(x)] + O(\exp\{-2q\})\tag{2.50}$$

I tried to get that (2.48) by Taylor therom whichever on individual variable $$ \exp\{-q\} $$ or multivaribles x and $$ \exp\{-q\} $$, but failed.

For example, for individual variable:
   Let $$ \exp\{-q\} $$ = t. For the reason that the theorem of taylor, when expends f(x) at the point a,  we will get f(x) =  f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + O(x^2), like this i can think the exp{-q} as t.
Help. Thanks.

Comment: After answering, I notice now that this question has already been asked & answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530873/16397 -- also, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/531567/16397

Comment: Sorry, i did not notice that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 2.50 is obtained from Equation 2.48 by considering $q\to\infty$ (independent of $x$) and applying Taylor's theorem; thus, letting $\delta=e^{-q}\to 0$, (2.48) gives

$$\begin{align}
y&= \frac{S(x)}{1-\delta}\\ \\
S(y)&= S\left[\frac{S(x)}{1-\delta}\right]\\ \\
&= S\left[S(x)(1+\delta+O(\delta^2)\right]=S\left[S(x)+ S(x)\,\delta+S(x)\,O(\delta^2)\right]\tag{1}\\ \\
&= S\left[S(x)\right]+S'[S(x)]\,S(x)\,\delta+O(\delta^2)\tag{2}\\ \\
\end{align}$$
where we've twice used Taylor's Theorem in the following form$(^*)$:

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $f,f',f''$ exist and are continuous on a closed interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$, then for all $t,a\in I$,
>   $$f(t) = f(a) +f'(a)\,(t-a)+O((t-a)^2).$$

To get (1), apply the theorem to $f(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$, $t=\delta$, and $a=0$. To get (2), apply the theorem to $f=S$, $t=S(x)+S(x)\,\delta$, and $a=S(x)$.

$(^*)$ Jaynes tacitly assumes that the function $S$ satisfies the conditions required for Taylor's theorem to apply.

Comment: Thanks very much, this problem has stuck me for almost two entire days.  Now i am very happy with your beautiful answer. Thanks again.

Comment: The (∗) Jaynes tacitly assumes that the function S meets the conditions required for Taylor's theorem to hold, do you mean that it is not a very rigid proof?

Comment: @hello_god -  Jaynes explicitly states that $S$ is assumed to be continuous and monotonically decreasing on $[0,1]$, with extreme values $S(0)=1,\,S(1)=0$. If Taylor's theorerm in the stated form is to apply, then the tacit part is that its first two derivatives are also assumed to exist and be continuous on the same interval. (Apparently in reference to this, Jaynes says R. T. Cox [1946] derived the same result assuming $S$ to be twice differentiable -- which Jaynes says he considers a " very innocuous" assumption on grounds of "common
sense".)